# JavaFX application intermittently shows an empty window

Tags: java, javafx

I just started to develop an application with `JavaFX` and this is the first time I am using `JavaFX`.

My application works fine, but sometimes (happened twice) when I start the application, it only shows an empty window, without any content. When this happens, no matter what I do, I cannot get it fixed until I restart the PC. When I restart the PC, the issue automatically gets resolved.

Following are my environment details

- `Windows 7 64bit`.
- `jdk1.8.0_131` (64 bit).
- Build with `Maven` `v3.2.5`
- Developed in `IntelliJ IDEA 2017`. (When issue occurs, window is empty
  when opened through IDEA, and opened through
  myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar built by maven)

What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: There is another old post with answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474164/empty-window-showing-up-when-running-javafx-application-using-both-graphic-view

Comment: @jan, my issue is different. The issue gets resolved with no code change when the PC is restarted.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a GPU driver issue... does this happen when running with `-Dprism.order=sw`?  (forcing software rendering)

Comment: @sillyfly, I haven't tried this. I will try this and check. Thanks.